# ActiveRecord where.not on text field in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

My ActiveRecord model `PaperTrail::Version` has a field named `whodunnit` of type `text`.

I want to make a `where.not` query on this field:

```
PaperTrail::Version.where.not(:whodunnit => 4)
```

That works fine on SQLite but if fails on PostgreSQL:

```
2014-12-04T07:21:42.484139+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <> integer
2014-12-04T07:21:42.484142+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ....("versions"."whodunnit" != 4)  ORD...
```

How should I change my query to make it work on both databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like *SQLite* is implicily casting the `varchar` to an `integer` for you. *Postgres* does not do that, so as to reduce the chance for accidental data loss / unexpected behavior.

In *Postgres*, you can explicitly cast from an `integer` to a `varchar` or vice versa using `::<type>`. (Although from the error above, it appears your *Postgres* model has it as a `text` type, which is *Postgres* specific, although in many ways it behaves like a `varchar`.)

I suspect the most straightforward way to do this without special casing is to convert the `4` to a string, which I would expect *Rails* to then in turn generate SQL that is more compatible.

So, something like this:

```
PaperTrail::Version.where.not(:whodunnit => 4.to_s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't change the given integer to a string before trying to apply it to the query. Simply changing the 4 to '4' should fix the issue.

```
PaperTrail::Version.where.not(:whodunnit => '4')
```

I went ahead and tested this on my local system just now, and it works to pass an integer into the query using Postgres 9.3.5. Which version are you using?

Comment: That's version 9.3.3 (on Heroku)

Comment: Yeah, just change 4 to '4' (or 4.to_s like khampson said) and it should work.